# Customization Bottom Sheet Dialog's View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-bottomsheetdialog

I just want to get the `BottomSheetDialog` like below: margin from the system window. How can I get like this?

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can create Bottom Sheet Dialog Fragment in following way:

First create the xml file as below named as

> fragment_bottomsheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_corner_white3"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_select_address"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:background="@drawable/round_corner_gray"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="Select Address" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now create a Bottom Sheet Fragment named as

> BottomSheetFragment

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetDialogFragment;
import android.view.View;

public class BottomSheetFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

    public static BottomSheetFragment newInstance() {
        BottomSheetFragment fragment = new BottomSheetFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void setupDialog(Dialog dialog, int style) {
        View contentView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.fragment_bottomsheet, null);
        dialog.setContentView(contentView);
        ((View) contentView.getParent()).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
    }

}
```

To call that bottom sheet fragment you can write as below:

```
BottomSheetFragment bottomSheetDialog = BottomSheetFragment.newInstance();
bottomSheetDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Bottom Sheet Dialog Fragment");
```

I have only took a single textview for now and attaching the screenshot because your main concern is to get margin in bottomsheet. Also in this way you can customize bottom sheet as you want. Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Better override `onCreateView(...){return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dlg_layout, null)}` rather then `setupDialog`

Comment: No round corners and margin for me thou

Comment: @NickUnuchek: it produce error `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setBackgroundColor(int)' on a null object reference`

Comment: @C.F.G work with view before return it from fun: ```override onCreateView(...) {val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dlg_layout, null); view.setBackgroundColor(int); return view}```

Comment: These methods are not user friendly, use this to cancel the dialog when click on margins: `parent.setOnClickListener {dismiss() }`

Answer (score 2):

Use this in your styles. Create a folder in values called styles and use this code.

```
<style name="BottomSheetDialogTheme" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/BottomSheetStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="BottomSheetStyle" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Now set it as a background in your Fragment class

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottom_sheet, container, false);

    textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textview);

    return view;
}
```

And for the round corners simply create a drawable with a simple shape in it and rounded corners (for example, drawable/bottom_sheet_background.xml)

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/white" />
    <corners android:radius="18dp" />
</shape>
```

Finally don't forget to assign it to your layout's root element

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_sheet_background"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/easy_tv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/toast_background"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Select Address"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a folder in values called styles and use below styles/code:

```
<style name="BottomSheetDialogTheme" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/BottomSheetStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="BottomSheetStyle" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

To call that bottom sheet fragment you can write as below:

```
BottomSheetDialog bottomSheet = new BottomSheetDialog(Activity.this,
                                                      R.style.BottomSheetDialogTheme);
bottomSheet.setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
bottomSheet.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

More standard form of the Accepted answer (`setupDialog` replacement):

> `bottom_sheet.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_corner_white3"
            android:orientation="vertical">
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_select_address"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:background="@drawable/round_corner_gray"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="Select Address" />
    
        </RelativeLayout>
    
    </RelativeLayout>
```

> `BottomSheetFragment.java`

```
    import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetDialogFragment;
    import android.view.View;
    
    public class BottomSheetFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {
    
        public static BottomSheetFragment newInstance() {
            BottomSheetFragment fragment = new BottomSheetFragment();
            return fragment;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }
    
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet, container,false);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        
            ((View) view.getParent()).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
        
            //other views ... 
        }
    
    }
```

[image]