# how to Implement bottom sheet

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I want to Implement something smaller to that image when user click icon, button... it show to the user the opinions and cancel

[image: overlay screen]

Comment: That is called a bottom sheet.

Comment: ok thanks I was searching for the wrong thing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Customization Bottom Sheet Dialog's View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55218663/customization-bottom-sheet-dialogs-view)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use what's provided by Jetpack Compose, find more info here
[Jetpack Compose Scaffold + Modal Bottom Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67744381/jetpack-compose-scaffold-modal-bottom-sheet)

Or you can make you own, here's an example implementation

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyCustomBottomSheetScaffold(
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
    isBottomSheetVisible: Boolean,
    onDismissRequest: () -> Unit,
    bottom: @Composable () -> Unit,
    overlayColor: Color = Color(0xAA_000000),
) {
    val actualOverlayColor = animateColorAsState(if (isBottomSheetVisible) overlayColor else Color.Transparent).value

    Box {
        content()

        Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize()
            .then(if (isBottomSheetVisible) Modifier.clickable { onDismissRequest() } else Modifier)
            .background(
                actualOverlayColor
            ),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomCenter
        ) {
            AnimatedVisibility(
                isBottomSheetVisible,
                enter = slideInVertically(initialOffsetY = { it }),
                exit = slideOutVertically(targetOffsetY = { it }),
            ) {
                bottom()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's how to use it

```kotlin
@Composable
fun BottomSheetExample() {
    // When this is true, the bottom sheet gets expanded
    var isBottomSheetVisible by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    MyCustomBottomSheetScaffold(
        content = {
            // Content goes here
            Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(Color.Blue), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
                Button(onClick = { isBottomSheetVisible = true }) {
                    Text("Open")
                }
            }
        },
        isBottomSheetVisible = isBottomSheetVisible,
        onDismissRequest = { isBottomSheetVisible = false },
        bottom = {
            // Bottom sheet content goes here
            Box(
                Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                    .background(Color.White)
                    .clickable {
                        isBottomSheetVisible = false
                    }
                    .padding(16.dp),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
            ) {
                Text("Close")

            }
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just one clarification, if you decide to go with this answer (suggested by Benoit TH): [Jetpack Compose Scaffold + Modal Bottom Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67744381/jetpack-compose-scaffold-modal-bottom-sheet)

You will need to use `ModalBottomSheetLayout` to have a bottom sheet with gray background above it like you showed in the example image provided.
If you use the *regular* `BottomSheetScaffold` the behaviour is different, being the bottom sheet displayed without background on above it.

**EDIT**:

Take into account that Material 3 **removed** these components (why google, why!?) so in case you want to use them (or you are migrating to Material 3), just  copy the source code from Material into your project.
(that's what I did, to be able to use `ModalBottomSheetLayout` in a project with Material 3)